# For loop stopping?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub InstagramHttp()
    Output.Items.Clear()
    Button2.Enabled = False
    StopCheck.Enabled = True
    isRunning = True

    For i = 0 To Names.Items.Count - 1
        Dim name As String = CStr(Names.Items(i))
        Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://www.instagram.com/" + name), HttpWebRequest)

        Try
            Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = CType(Request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            MessageBox.Show(Response.StatusCode)
            If Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                Continue For
            End If
        Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Status)
            If ex.Status = 7 Then
                Output.Items.Add(name)
            End If
            Continue For
        End Try
    Next

    MessageBox.Show("Checker Finished!")
    Button2.Enabled = True
    StopCheck.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

There's my code. For some reason the status message only shows up twice. Then the loop stops completely. I get two "200" popups then the code doesn't run anymore. There are more than 2 elements in the list.

Comment: When providing a title for your question, it should be a summary of the issue only.  Don't specify the language; that's what tags are for.  Don't say things like "please help"; no one would be posting in the first place if they didn't need help.

Comment: As for the issue, have you debugged your code?  The answer is almost certainly "no", so posting a question here is premature.  Place a breakpoint at the top of the code and step through it line by line.  You can then see exactly what path execution takes and what values all your variables have at every step.

Comment: Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour]